# How to set div's property by jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want some hide/show functionality with my div tag. I am using below code to do that but its not working.

`.aspx`

```
    <div id="divCust" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" visible="false">
         abc Test
        </div>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick="return editDetail();" runat="server"
                Text="Add"/>
```

`.js file`

```
function editDetail() {
    $('#divCust').css("display", "block");
}
```

What i missing in this code??Is it ok or what?? If any one have any idea about this than please help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`visible` != `display`

Write `style="display: none;"` in your div instead of `visible = "false"` and your code should work.